# Is there a way to attach multiple screenshots at once in Azure Devops test runner?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, manual-testing

I'm running a manual test on Azure Devops / TFS, and I'm sturggling with attaching files/ screenshots that I would like saved on my computer.

Is there a way to attach multiple screenshots at once? The current attachment window allows only 1 file/ screenshot at a time.

[Attachment window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6XH2.png)

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to attach multiple screenshots at once?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method could meet your requirements.

It only supports uploading one file at a time in Test Runner UI.

**Workaround:**

You could try to use the Powershell script to run Rest API to achieve it.

Here is the sample:

```
$files = @("filepath1","filepath2")
For ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Length; $i++) 
{
echo $files[$i]

$filename = $files[$i]

$parts = $filename.split("\")

$name = echo $parts[4]

echo $name


$file= [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$filename")
$Base64file= [Convert]::ToBase64String($file)
echo $Base64file


$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/test/Runs/{RunId}/Results/{TestResultID}/Attachments?iterationId=1&api-version=5.0-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = "
    {
       `"stream`": `"$Base64file`",
       `"fileName`": `"$name`",
       `"comment`": `"Test attachment upload`",
       `"attachmentType`": `"GeneralAttachment`"
    }"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

}
```

The powershell script will traverse the file path and upload it to the test result attachment.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the suggested option if you want to do it manually without using rest API.
Then you can upload screenshots individually or you can copy the file in the description section on TFS, you can do the copy-paste as many times as you want.